# ¿Cómo funcionan las funciones min() y max() sin el group by?

Tags: mysql

En un primer punto se me pide saber cual es la cantidad de estudiantes que tiene cada carrera, esto lo hice con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT carrera.nombre,COUNT(estudiante.cod_carrera) AS cantidad FROM estudiante 
INNER JOIN carrera ON estudiante.cod_carrera=carrera.codigo 
GROUP BY carrera.codigo;
```

y me da como resultado:

[image: Resultado consulta 1]

Después me piden mostrar las carreras con más y menos estudiante en una misma consulta, bueno se me ocurrió hacerlo primero en consultas separadas y luego juntarlo en una sola consulta, pero aquí fue donde encontré el error y quiero saber como es que funcionan `max()` y `min()` para que esto pase.

bueno el código sql que usé es el siguiente :

```
SELECT nombre,MAX(cantidad) FROM (
SELECT carrera.nombre,COUNT(estudiante.cod_carrera) AS cantidad FROM estudiante 
INNER JOIN carrera ON estudiante.cod_carrera=carrera.codigo 
GROUP BY carrera.codigo) as t1;
```

y obtuve como resultado :

[image: Resultado consulta 2.1]

la cual en un principio es un resultado correcto, pero cuando intenté lo mismo con el `min()` entonces fue donde obtuve el problema, obteniendo como resultado lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces fue que me dí cuenta que el `min()` o el `max()` me esta devolviendo el nombre del primer valor de la tabla y el valor que devuelven las funciones.

Quiero saber como es que funcionan el `min()` y el `max()` para entender porque pasa esto.

Answer (score 2):

Por empezar digamos que esta sentencia sin especificación de `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT nombre, MAX(cantidad) 
       FROM ( ... )
```

Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic
>   which name value to choose for the group.

Nos dice, que se retornará un único grupo, dónde `nombre` es indeterminado, es decir podrá ser cualquiera de los `nombre` de la tabla. El `MAX(cantidad)` o `MIN(cantidad)` será válido, pero el nombre podrá ser cualquiera.

Esta construcción es inconsistente con la especificación `SQL-92`, dónde es obligatorio, al combinar columnas con funciones de agregación (como `MAX`o `MIN`), indicar las columnas en un `GROUP BY`. Salvo en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) (hasta dónde sé), en el resto de los motores, no funciona. De hecho, es recomendable para versiones anteriores de la 5.7, configurar [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), para hacer consistente el funcionamiento con el estándar, y una sentencia como la anterior dé un error.

Para hacer lo que buscas, es decir, buscar el grupo con el valor máximo o mínimo, una posibilidad es esta:

```
SELECT t1.nombre, 
       t1.cantidad
       FROM (SELECT carrera.nombre, 
                    COUNT(estudiante.cod_carrera) AS cantidad 
                    FROM estudiante 
                    INNER JOIN carrera ON estudiante.cod_carrera=carrera.codigo 
                    GROUP BY carrera.nombre
            ) as t1

        INNER JOIN (SELECT  MAX(cantidad) AS max_cantidad 
                        FROM (SELECT COUNT(estudiante.cod_carrera) AS cantidad 
                                    FROM estudiante 
                                    INNER JOIN carrera ON estudiante.cod_carrera=carrera.codigo 
                                    GROUP BY carrera.nombre
                        ) as t2
                        ON t1.cantidad = t2.max_cantidad
```

Esto debería retornarte todos los grupos con el valor mínimo ( 1 o más).

Comment: Excelente respuesta Patricio. Si el OP activase el modo `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` de este modo `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` estoy casi seguro que la consulta que muestra en la pregunta no funcionaría. Creo que por disciplina se debería activar este modo siempre que vayamos a escribir consultas de agrupación, precisamente porque esa *permisividad* de MySQL puede conducir a escribir consultas que funcionan pero que no son conformes al estándar.

Answer (score 0):

la función MAX(cantidad) devolverá el numero mas alto que encuentre en la columna cantidad, así mismo la función MIN(cantidad) devolverá el numero mas bajo que encuentre de la columna cantidad.

Espero haber aclarado tu duda.

Comment: creo que la pregunta no va por ahi, si no por como se comporta en sus resultados, por que estas deacuerdo que por eso el OP esta poniendo código e imágenes de su escenario